# How do you add an if statement properly to an html.erb file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When rendering the index page I want to collect the values for POC and Model type from other tables. If those fields are in the other tables it works just fine. The problem is if that field is empty it breaks. I decided to add an if statement and am getting error cannot find on ID.

```
<h1>Hardwares</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Serial Number</th>
      <th>Model Number</th>
      <th>Model Type</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>POC</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @hardwares.each do |hardware| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= hardware.serialnumber %></td>
        <td><%= hardware.modelnumber %></td>
        <% if Modeltype.find(hardware.modeltype_id) != nil %>
          <td><%= Modeltype.find(hardware.modeltype_id).mtype%></td>
        <% else %>
          <td>hi</td>
        <% end %>
        <td><%= hardware.location %></td>
        <td><%= Poc.find(hardware.poc_id).name%></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', hardware %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_hardware_path(hardware) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', hardware, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<a href="hardwares/new" class="button round">New Hardware</a>
```

The issue appears to be with the if statement, is my syntax for the if statement correct?

I have also tried:

```
<% if Modeltype.find(hardware.modeltype_id) == true %>
  <td><%= Modeltype.find(hardware.modeltype_id).mtype%></td>
<% else %>
  <td>hi</td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

in Ruby, the null value is `nil`, not `nill`. And every object that isn't `false` or `nil` is truthy. So, you don't need to explicitly check whether the call to `find` returns `nil` or not.

You can also do variable assignment inline. So, your code would become:

```
<% if (model_type = Modeltype.find_by(id: hardware.modeltype_id)) %>
  <td><%= model_type.mtype %></td>
<% else %>
  <td>hi</td>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: Just to give an explanation of where I went wrong there - `find` throws an error if the ID you're looking for isn't found. So you can use `where(...).first` (as suggested in the comments), I usually use `find_by(id: 123)`. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I had used nil, that was a typo on my part. But I just tried yours and still get this error: "Couldn't find Modeltype with 'id'=" with the if line in red.

Comment: @TimR: try `if (model_type = Modeltype.where(id: hardware.modeltype_id).first)`